# session's variables values retrieving in _LayoutPartial in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, session-variables

I'm filling values to a session's like following to retrive those in _LayoutPartial view

```
if (userdata != null)
{
    Session["userdata"] = new SampleViewModel { FirstName = userdata.UserFirstName, LastName = userdata.UserLastName };
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginmodel.UserName, false);
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home", new { username = loginmodel.UserName });
}
```

I want to retrive those values in _LayoutPartial View , So I tried somethin like following

```
<a class="sa">
    (@Session["userdata"] as ProjectName.Models.SampleViewModel).FirstName 
    (@Session["userdata"] as ProjectName.Models.SampleViewModel).LastName
</a>
```

But this is not retrieving data properly . In this _LoginPartial I'm not Referencing any model also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your parenthesis in the wrong spot, and you need a double set - one for the casting (inner set) and one for the razor execution (outer set). It needs to be

```
@((Session["userdata"] as ProjectName.Models.SampleViewModel).Name)
```

Comment: Is that the my approach optimum way , show the user.FirstName , user.LastName on _LayoutPartial if I'm not following any membership providers

Comment: Personally I would have a base view model that is used in the view and I would be adding the values to the `FormAuthenticationTicket`, rather than using `Session`, but there is nothing wrong with what your doing

Comment: If this `@((Session["userdata"] as ProjectName.Models.SampleViewModel).Name)` getting null , when view loading then run time error is occurring , how to avoid that and store this inside a variable to reuse easily ?

Comment: You need to check for `null` first - e.g. `@{ var userData = Session["userdata"] as ProjectName.Models.SampleViewModel; }` then `@if(userData != null} { <a class="sa">@userData.FirstName @userData.FirstName</a> }`